# GAP code to construct a faithful permutation representation using three subgroups

Tags: gap

I'm new to GAP, and I tried to adjust the code that ahulpke wrote at the link: [Faithful permutation representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241546/faithful-permutation-representation?rq=1)

to construct a faithful representation of the group $C_2\times (C_4\rtimes C_4)$ using "three orbits". I adujested the code by adding a subgroup $H_3$, and

cos:=Concatenation(RightCosets(G,H1),RightCosets(G,H2),RightCosets(G,H3));

But it didn’t work with me and I believe I made an error.

Do any GAP's codes exist that will give me a faithful permutation representation of a group with respect to provided three subgroups, where the intersection of both subgroups has a trivial core?

I appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: What did you do (concrete input and commands used) and what went wrong (wrong result? Error message?)

Comment: gap> f := FreeGroup( "a", "b","c");;
gap> h := f / [ f.1^2, f.2^4,f.3^4,f.1^-1*f.2^-1*f.1*f.2,f.1^-1*f.3^-1*f.1*f.3,f.3*f.2*f.3^-1*f.2];
<fp group on the g\
enerators 
[ a, b, c ]>
gap> H1:=SmallGroup(16,2);
<pc group of size 
16 with 
4 generators>
gap> H2:=SmallGroup(8,2);
<pc group of size 
8 with 
3 generators>
gap> H3:=SmallGroup(8,2);
<pc group of size 
8 with 
3 generators>
gap> cos:=Concatenation(RightCosets(G,H1),RightCosets(G,H2),RightCosets(G,H3));
Error, Variable: 'G' must\
 have a value
not in any functio\
n at *stdin*:9

Comment: @ahulpke, above what I did and the message error that I got.

Comment: I was trying to find the faithful permutation representation, by utilising the action on the right cosets of $H1= <b, c>$, $H2= <a, c>$ and $H3= <a, b>$.

Comment: You need to use the correct variable names, your group is called `h`, not `G`, and you need to use actual subgroups of your group, not just groups that are isomorphic to them.

Comment: @ahulpke, thank you for brining this to my attention, I corrected the code and is working now.